# How to make Tomcat run a Spring/React app (Showing 404 not found)?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, tomcat, frontend

I have created an app with Spring Boot and React. It works perfectly fine if I run via Run As -> Spring Boot App. But when I make a war package with Maven (Clean Package) it shows 404 not found when I deploy it via Tomcat manager. My build plugins:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>build-frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>position-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have a guess it has something to do with port 3000 in React (though I proxied in json package). My frontend is under src/main/frontend. in main I use

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MapRunnerApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MapRunnerApp.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MapRunnerApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: is API working?

Comment: When I run as spring boot app all api is working, yes

Comment: No I am asking while running in tomcat, just check that API is working or not. Like any health API or anything you can access using postman or from browser directly !

Comment: Sorry, was checking. Yep, it is working!! via localhost:3000 i still can do what i could! Just doesn't show the main page on tomcat with path http://localhost:8080/map-runner/ (my context path is the same as when running via boot)...